# GCC makefile on Linux with Multiple *.c files

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I need to create a MakeFile for those files:

1. main.c
2. ceaser.c
3. ceaser.h

I tried this:

```
all: task1
task1 : main.o ceaser.o gcc main.o ceaser.o task1.o -o task1
ceaser.o : ceaser.c ceaser.h gcc -c -g -Wall ceaser.c
main.o : main.c gcc -c -g -Wall main.c 
clean: rm *.o 
cleanall: rm task1 *.o
```

But when I'm trying to run it, it just says:

```
make: Nothing to be done for `MakeFile1'.
```

Comment: Note that makefile is going to execute commands only if it's needed (timestamp of source is newer than output file). Remove all *.o files and task1 file and check if it works. You've got also bad indentation, but I suppose It's just a matter of stackoverflow formatting

Comment: You seem to be missing (at least) several newlines from your code snippet.

Comment: all the other files are deleted but it still does that

Answer (score 1):

For it to be a proper makefile, the formatting is vital or it simply won't work.

```
all: task1

task1 : main.o ceaser.o 
        gcc main.o ceaser.o  -o task1

ceaser.o : ceaser.c ceaser.h 
        gcc -c -g -Wall ceaser.c -o $@

main.o : main.c 
        gcc -c -g -Wall main.c -o $@

clean: 
        rm *.o 

cleanall: 
        rm task1 *.o
```

Note, too, that those must be tab characters rather than spaces that precede each action line.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Edward's answer, a simplified version

```
all: task1

task1 : main.o ceaser.o 
        gcc $^ -o $@

%.o : %.c
        gcc -c -g -Wall $< -o $@

clean: 
        rm *.o 

cleanall: 
        rm task1 *.o
```

Where "$?" is the list of dependencies, "$@" is the target output and "$<" is the first dependent.

Comment: It's a good answer, but you really want `$^` instead of `$?` in that context.  The difference is that `$^` includes all prerequisites, while `$?` only includes the ones newer than the target.  For the linking stage we always want all `.o` files included.

Comment: $? includes the targets that have changed since the last make was called. So it doesn't always try to build the target that are available but haven't changed. In case of $^, irrespective of the time-stamp all the targets are built.

Comment: The problem is that if you update `main.c` but not `ceaser.c` the link step will be `gcc main.o -o task1` which is wrong because it fails to include `ceaser.o`.